# How to make tool window maximum size set to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows Forms application that I am making where I have a sizeable tool window with a datagridview filling up it's entirely.

The datagridview is bigger than the window's default size so I made it so the user can expand the window however the form is able to expand past the size of the datagridview which makes it look odd. You can see past the grid and the background color of the form is revealed, etc.

Is there a way to make the window where it can only be expanded to the maximum size of the full datagridview?

Comment: yes, you can prevent changes and do snap to sizes by using windows properties - like maximumsize

Comment: Set the Dock property of the DataGridView to full and the min/max size of the form to the dimension of the DataGridView. This needs no coding

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on another post:

```
int dgv_width = dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
int dgv_height = dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowsHeight(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible);
this.Width = dgv_width;
this.Height = dgv_height;
```